# Javascript as embedded resource in a .NET Class library?

Tags: .net, embedded-resource

I'm running an MVC project which references a class library. The class library contains a *javascript* file which build action is set to "*Embedded resource*".

**What actually happens to the file?** I can't seem to get it using the `ResourceManager` because I have no idea of the namespace it puts the resource in.

My class library file structure:

- /Project
- /Project/Web
- /Project/Web/Js
- /Project/Web/Js/Test.js << embedded resource

Code:

```
var t = this.GetType().Assembly;
var r = new System.Resources.ResourceManager("Namespace", t); //What is the namespace here?
var js = r.GetObject("Test.js");
```

Comment: The root namespace of your assembly.

Comment: Doesn't work. I'm getting the following exception: "Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "YourNamespace.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "YourNamespace.Project" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I dont have access to a compiler right now so the following might contain slight errors.

```
var asm = typeof(MyClass).Assembly;
var stream = asm. GetManifestResourceStream("<rootnamespace>.Project.Web.Js.Test.js");
var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
String source = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Notes:

- use `typeof(x)` instead of `GetType()`. The latter will give incorrect result if you inherit from the type.
- rootnamespace can be found/set in the project settings. (I assumed that "Project" is a folder inside the project in my example)
- asp.net has a pre-build solution for using resources this way. Try looking into `Page.ClientScript` for this. (I'm not sure if this also works for MVC, but would bet that it would)